# Regex/String based conditional statements on Google Sheets

Tags: database, google-sheets, conditional-statements

NOOB QUESTION - I'm a marketer with very minimal coding experience, I need your help with sheets.

I have a database with 26k entries.

I need to apply this condition.

If cell contains NULL, output "NA".
Else if cell contains city1 OR city2 OR city3 OR city4 OR city5 OR city6 OR city7, output "Metro"
Else output "Non Metro"

What is the right sheets formula for this?

I tried Regex, but I'm not sure how to add the OR statement in the syntax - I keep getting an error thrown at me.

Comment: `Else if cell contains city1` It's not clear whether and why REGEX applies in this case but the word `contains` is significant in any solution. Would you please edit your question to provide some sample data and an example of the successful outcome. Please include the sample data as text, you can create a free, online markdown table at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(A1,"NULL"),"NA",REGEXMATCH(A1,"(?i)city1|city2|city3|city4|city5|city6|city7"),"Metro",1,"Non Metro")
```